# How to get all the columns that has leading spaces in data?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table with around 100 columns, I could get for a single column by using the following query

```
Select * from tes_tbl where col_1 like ' %'
```

But how can I retrieve all the columns in a single query

Im using oracle database

P.s: l'm a beginner to SQL

Comment: I think you are working around the actual problem, why would you have a 100 columns?

Comment: There should not be any data in the table with leading spaces. The table has nearly 3 lakh records and I wanted to check that.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

You've not specified which sort of SQL so I'm going to assume MS SQL Server.

As others have pointed out you can generate a query along the lines of

```
select * from tes_tbl where col_1 like '% ' OR col_2 like '% '
```

However you've mentioned that you've got a lot of columns to query. (This is the MSSQL specific bit) You can query [Information Schema](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) to get a list of the columns in your table:

```
select 'OR [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] like '' % ''' from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'tes_tbl'
```

This will give you a list of OR clauses for each of the columns. You can use these to build your query (replacing the part of the WHERE clause in the query above).

You can also use this trick to explicitly name the columns in the select which is often a good idea for anything other than ad-hoc queries.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. I'm using Oracle DBMS

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OR` operator as like below,

```
Select * from tes_tbl where col_1 like '%' OR col_2 like '%'
```

This will give you the result set which satisfies the conditions in `WHERE` clause

Comment: That will return all rows that have a value in one of the columns. Not the rows where one column starts with a blank.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I just suggested he/she to use OR operator and am not sure of the condition..